# Artifactory 7.x setup with private root CA

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, artifactory

I've been trying to get the built in Tomcat in v7 to work with our internally generated CA. In v6 I would just put the jks path and password in the tomcat connector, but in v7 you need to put the details in system.yaml. I have not found any combination that works. Support has been trying to help, but they haven't gotten it working either. I have a root CA, a system CA and key. I can use them with Apache fine. But I can't find the details anywhere to configure the internal tomcat correctly in system.yaml. It can't be this hard, right?

Answer (score 2):

Did this documentation page not help you? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+TLS+Certificates

This has all the details you need. Let us know if this does not work for you.

It is no more just jks store path, but bootstrapping the services with the certifacate you need.